# Does setInterval leak?

Tags: javascript

i'm doing some javascript, where I repeadetly click a button, using

```
setInterval(function(){
    clickmyButton()
}, 500);
```

Eventually clickmyButton will send the user to another page (via window.location.href="Other page"). I was wondering, since I never called clearInterval within the function will it cause a leak? I just assumed that since the page goes to another page, the javascript on the old page will stop running and be cleaned up.

Comment: As a side note, you could skip the anonymous function there and just pass `clickmyButton` to `setInterval()`.

Comment: Just explaining what @alex said: `setInterval(clickmyButton, 500);`

Answer (score 3):

That is correct. Once the page closes, all the javascript running is discarded, and all of the memory associated with its variables is cleared.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't. The memory occupied should be set to overwritable or cleared on the new page load.

Comment: +1 for **shouldn't**. There have been cases of faulty garbage collection before, no doubt there will be in the future. It is a reasonable strategy to cancel the timeout before re-directing just in case. It is also a good strategy to have a function calling itself using *setTimeout* so that when it redirects, it doesn't set another timeout (which is effectively the same as cancelling *setInterval* before redirecting).

Comment: While I agree that GC's have flaws, I doubt you'll get much value out of trying to compensate for them.  You need the implementer (in this case, of the browser or the JS engine) to get off his patootie and fix the problem.